# Decimal to Binary encoder in proteus

Tags: proteus

[image: Decimal to binary encoder using IC 74147]

I am trying to make Decimal to binary encoder using IC 74147 in Proteus. But Led's are not lighting up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like a 74148 in your circuit and not having GS or EO connected to something sensible could make all the difference. Make sure power is connected too.

Comment: @Andy GS & EO are outputs according to the datasheet

Comment: The LEDs may be connected backwards, plus each one needs a ballast resistor. Also, cosmetically, your schematic is upside-down

Answer (score 1):

Inputs and outputs are active low. Try turning off all but sw2.3.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the leds don't turn on, why didn't you connect the inverters to the output of the 74ls148